# Intuition for universal pair of unitaries and group $C^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $F_2$ be the free group on two generators. If $\pi$ is the universal unitary representation of $F_2$ on a Hilbert space ${\cal H}$, then the group $C^*$-algebra $C^*(F_2)$ is the $C^*$-subalgebra of $B({\cal H})$ generated by $\{\pi(g):g\in F_2\}$.

Alternatively:

Let $U,V$ be two unitary operators on a Hilbert space ${\cal H}$. Then $(U,V)$ is a *universal pair of unitaries* if for each pair of unitary operators $(U_1,V_1)$ on a Hilbert space ${\cal H}_1$, the assignment $U\mapsto U_1$ and $V\mapsto V_1$ extends to a $*$-homomorphism from $C^*(U,V)$ onto $C^*(U_1,V_1)$. In this case, $C^*(F_2)$ is the $C^*$-algebra generated by a universal pair of unitaries.

For the existence of such universal pair, M.-D. Choi said that we may simply let $U=\oplus U_\alpha$ and $V=\oplus V_\alpha$ where $(U_\alpha,V_\alpha)$ runs through all possible pairs of unitary operators on a fixed separable Hilbert space.

**Question**: In the first definition, in my mind we can safely assume that the two generators of $F_2$ do not have dependence. How do we make sure that this is also case for the direct sum construction above? In particular, say if I already know $U=\oplus U_\alpha$, then how do I form $V$? I think we cannot have $V$ to be a multiple of $U$ for example.

Comment: I don't understand your question because $U$ is formed at the same time as $V$ from the set of all pairs $(U_\alpha,V_\alpha)$.

Comment: @Ruy, it was my attempt to understand the direct sum construction. My confusion is about the part ``$(U_\alpha,V_\alpha)$ runs through all possible pairs...''. I don't quite understand what is meant by that. I understand it to be the cartesian product of unitary group with unitary group. What if the set was formed so that $V_\alpha=U_\alpha$? Sorry if stupid questions.

Comment: That sentence is to be taken literally.  Every single pair $(U,V)$ is present there!  For some pairs, $U$ and $V$ could coincide, but there certainly exist pairs for which $U\neq V$ .

Comment: You are correct about the cartesian product of the unitary group.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! So $U$ is identified with all possible *first coordinate* in the cartesian product and $V$ is identified with all possible *second coordinate*. Perhaps a minor point: how is it possible that an indexing set exists? Also, I take it that there's nothing stopping anyone to consider cartesian product of unitary group $n$ times which would correspond to the free group on $n$ generators?

Comment: Any set may be indexed:  given a set $X$, if no better index set $A$ exists,  one can always take $A=X$, and for
every $\alpha \in A$,  one may define $x_\alpha $ to be $\alpha $ itself (notice that $X$ is playing both roles at the same time).  It might
sound  a bit cynical but it is then  totally correct to  say that $X=\{x_\alpha :\alpha \in A\}$.  In other words, the indexing function
  $$
  \alpha \in A\mapsto x_\alpha \in X
  $$
  is the identity function!

Comment: Regarding the $U_\alpha $ and $V_\alpha $, one has
  $$
  \mathscr U(H)\times \mathscr U(H) =   \{(U_\alpha , V_\alpha ): \alpha \in  A\}
  $$
  while
  $$
  U=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha ,  \quad{\text{and}}\quad  V=\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} V_\alpha .
  $$
  So,  yes,  $U$ is made out of the first coordinates and $V$,
of the second.  Notice however that the same $U$ appears as the first coordinate of many pairs (one for each $V$ in
$\mathscr U(H)$), so the same $U$  shows up in that direct sum a lot of times!

Comment: Those are enormous unitaries then. Thanks for the discussion! It's a lot clearer now.

Comment: Yes, they ought to be since a lot is expected of them!